# Weekly Report UI form: choice of multi select controls

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

I am working on a report feature that requires the ability to allow the user to set a frequency for reports to be sent. In this case I am working on the weekly frequency.

Currently we are looking at the option of checkboxes to represent each day allowing the user to select as many days during the week.

I have also had the pattern used in email reports presented and have some questions that derived from from it.

In the first screenshot there is a segmented control for all of the days of the week. Monday is selected by default.

[image]

In the second screenshot I have selected two days for the report to run

[image]

In the third screenshot I have deselected Monday and Friday for reports and have attempted to schedule the report for two separate days. As the third screenshot shows I was unsuccessful.

[image]

Developers on the team have expressed comments that the user might not view a segmented control as multi-select and I'd tend to agree.

**Now for the questions:**

1. Is this a bug? I am able to select two report days if the default Monday is left selected. If it is a feature why do I have to always have Monday selected?
2. I haven't used a segmented control in this fashion before. I honestly cannot say that I have seen it used this way very often. Checkboxes would simplify the problem but this was the alternative solution presented to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Some applications use toggles like multiselect, but it can be clearer with checkboxes

Referring to **[omnifocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus)**, they use a toggle as a multiselect as well as a single select, both in close proximity to each other.

In my experience, i'm used to it (just my opinion! no research), but just below the multiselect is a single select, and they appear exactly the same:

#### Same control, different interaction:

[image]

#### And on mobile:

Notice how they have to give feedback to the user as to assure them of their selection above the toggle:

[image]

It looks like you have room for a row of checkboxes, and it makes it clearer:

[image]

#### Question 1: Is it a bug or a feature?

As for question number 1: if you have trouble knowing if it's a bug or a feature, assume the user will not have more context than you.

You can test both of these options before making a decision.

Comment: Perfect I was assuming that it might be a bug but I wasn't sure.  Its thrown into the testing queue for early next week so we should have a definitive answer. Its for a desktop only solution so I would lean towards the checkboxes.